# CoronaSDK content scaling issue

Tags: coronasdk

I am having an issue with scaling between iPhone3g, iPhone 4 and iPhone 5. I have used the ultimate config file here http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2012/12/04/the-ultimate-config-lua-file/ and I am setting my background image using:

```
bgimage = display.newImageRect("images/moonbase.png", 570, 360)
bgimage:setReferencePoint( display.CenterReferencePoint )
bgimage.x = _W / 2
bgimage.y = _H / 2
```

Part of the game I am developing the enemy follows a path, to draw this I created a line and used a bezier plugin. You will see from the following screenshots that the path and satelitte are in the wrong position. How can i get these to be the same across devices? Only zoomstretch seems to work but the images lose quality.

Screenshots: http://lukestirk.com/screen_resolution.png

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your bezier plugin should be made 'aware' of the

```
display.contentHeight
```

and fixed width=x,height=y settings should be removed from your config.lua file